# bootstrap datetimepicker inside jqgrid - control not visible fully

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using bootstrap datetimepicker control inside jqgrid. The datetimepicker control is not visible properly.

http://jsfiddle.net/cmpgtuwy/103/

```
 Please help
```

Comment: When I run your jsfiddle and check the console I see a 404 error against jqgrid. You might want to try a different CDN for jqgrid.js

Answer (score 1):

You demo used old jqGrid 4.6, which is not compatible with Bootstrap. I suggest you to use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.13.6 instead. Moreover, bootstrap-datetimepicker have problem if the editing field is inside of block, which has no `position: relative` style. Thus, I suggest to place the grid inside of outer div:

```html
<div id="outer" style="position: relative">
    <table id='grid'></table>
</div>
```

The next problem: your input data are in the format `data: "01/01/2015 03:30"`. You should to add `srcformat: 'd/m/Y H:i'` to inform the `formatter: "date"` about that.

The finally code could be

```js
var mydata = [
    { 
        data: "01/01/2015 03:30", 
        status: "OPEN"
    }, 
    { 
        data: "02/02/2015 03:45", 
        status: "ENTERED"
    }];

$("#grid").jqGrid({
    data: mydata,
    colModel: [
        { name: 'act', template: "actions" },
        { 
            name: 'data', 
            editrules: { required: true },
            formatter: 'date',
            formatoptions: {
                srcformat: 'd/m/Y H:i',
                newformat: 'd/m/Y H:i'
            },
            editable: true, 
            editoptions: {
                dataInit: function (el) {
                    $(el).datetimepicker({
                        locale: 'en-GB',
                        //debug: true,
                        widgetPositioning: {
                            horizontal: 'auto',
                            vertical: 'auto'
                        },
                        widgetParent: '#outer'
                    });
                    // fix the position of the datetimepicker
                    $(el).bind("dp.show", function () {
                        var $datepicker = $("#outer .bootstrap-datetimepicker-widget");
                        if ($datepicker.length > 0) {
                            $datepicker.css("top",
                                this.getBoundingClientRect().top +
                                window.pageYOffset +
                                $(this).outerHeight());
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'status',
            width: 180
        }
    ],
    iconSet: "fontAwesome",
    guiStyle: "bootstrap",
    hoverrows: false,
    pager: true   
});
```

See the demo http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/duooa5oy/1/